# How can I dynamically mount a host directory into a docker desktop k8s deployment on OSX?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm, docker-desktop

My team doesn't have all our code in the same place locally but we are all working on the same service. This service depends on a few other libraries and during the development it would be great to have the live version of those libs mounted into the pod for faster iteration.

How the path becomes dynamic doesn't matter, env var, config map, weird volume mount sorcery, etc...

My current approach uses helm to template out the yaml. I was hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
 volumes:
   - name: my-lib
     hostPath:
       path: $CODE_PATH/my_lib
 volumeMounts:
   - name: my-lib
     mountPath: /tmp/my_lib
```

Where my team members could externally define `CODE_PATH`, allowing them to point to where they keep their code. I'm not attached to a method for doing this. Currently, mine doesn't work anyway. I just need to be able to mount a host directory into a pod without statically defining an absolute path right in the yaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation there are 2 ways to achieve this but in both of them the `hostPath` has to be defined.

First approach would be to use [hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath), where `hostPath` volume uses the local disk of the node to mount the volume and specify the `hostPath` in Preferences->File Sharing in Docker Desktop.

Second approach would be to use a [PersistentVolume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage) approach in which cluster administrator creates the volumes and pods can access them through `PersistentVolumeClaims`, a level of abstraction between the volume and its storage mechanism.

Comment: I hadn't even considered adding a mount thought the UI directly. I can just ask  my team to specify a mount to their code directory that attaches to a predefined location on the node.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that @Jakub Siemaszko has a more correct answer to solve this without any extra tools, but I'll post the solution I ended up developing before their answer came in.

We use Makefiles and have .env files for our dev envs, so I ended up just telling people to put the path to where they keep their repo into the .env and using the Makefile to inject the var.

- ~/.user.env

  ```
  USER_CODE_PATH=/Users/LISTERINE/dev
  ```
- helm/Makefile

  ```
  # Attempt to export users vars into the make context
  ifneq (,$(wildcard ~/.user.env))
      include ~/.user.env
      export
  endif

  template:
      helm template webapp . -f dev-values.yaml --dry-run --set userCodePath=$(USER_CODE_PATH)
  ```
- helm/dev-values.yaml

  ```
  env: "dev"

  codeVolumes:
  # Code volumes are use to mount our source code into the pod.
  # Auto volumes specify the name of the dir that will be mounted into.
  # Auto volumes are sourced from your USER_CODE_PATH
  auto:
    - name: "my-db-lib"
      dir: "my-db-lib"
      module: "my_db_lib"
  ```
- helm/templates/deployment.yaml

  ```
  ...
  spec:
    ...
    template:
      ...
      spec:
        ...
        containers:
          - name: ...
            volumeMounts:
              {{- range .Values.codeVolumes.auto }}
              - name: {{ .name }}
                mountPath: "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/{{ .module }}"
              {{- end }}
              ...
        volumes:
          {{- if eq .Values.env "dev" }}
          {{- range .Values.codeVolumes.auto }}
          - name: {{ .name }}
            hostPath:
              path: "{{ $.Values.userCodePath }}/{{ .dir }}/{{ .module }}"
          {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
  ...
  ```

The key piece of this is that the Makefile is able to resolve their env vars that are defined outside the repository and export them into the makefile context so they can be passed into the helm template context using `--set`.
The section in `helm/templates/deployment.yaml` is protected to only try to get the user code mounts if it's running in dev.